# Adding vertical lines in line graph where y values are maximum?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, max, linegraph

I have a data frame consisting of 'time', intervals 0-2000 by 5 (x-axis), and 'number of steps', a range of 0-200. I'm using qplot, and I want to plot a `geom_vline` at the max of the number of steps. It is plotting a line, but at a really low point that I can't figure out. The code looks like the following:

Here is a rather poor recreation, but it suits none-the-less.

```
set.seed(2)
a<-seq(from=0,to=1000,by=5)
b<-sample(seq(from = 0, to = 100), size = 201, replace = TRUE)
df<-data.frame(a,b)
max(b)

qplot(a,b,df, geom='line')+
    geom_vline(xintercept=max(df$b),color='red')
```

You can see the `max(b)=99`, but the `geom_vline` isn't plotted there.

[image]

Comment: @ Pascal Perhaps, but these finer points are beyond me at the moment...I'm just trying to plot a line graph, and a vertical line that intersects at the x-axis where the y value is the greatest. If that involves scrapping this code so be it.

Comment: Not clean but does what you want: `geom_vline(xintercept=a[b == max(b)],color='red')`.

Comment: @Pascal It's not the leanest, but does the trick, and I think your comment in the prior post clarifies a bit why my initial approach didn't work. Tomorrow I will try ggplot instead of qplot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code is plotting the vertical line where `x` is equal 99, and at this position `y` is not maximum.

`geom_vline` can only be defined in terms where it crosses the `x` axis (the `xintercept` argument), and the correct way to go is to map which `x` values carry the maximum `y`.

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=a,y=b)) + 
  xlab("Time") + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,1000),breaks=seq(0,1000,50)) +
  ylab("Number os steps") + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100),breaks=seq(0,100,50)) +
  geom_line(size=1.2,color='grey40') +
  geom_vline(xintercept=a[b == max(b)],color='red') + #as suggested by user3710546
  geom_hline(yintercept=max(b),color='blue',linetype=2) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]